Can't use where properly in SearchKick
I'm attempting a rather simple query.
To show the data is actually in:
SearchService::Models::Message.search("393664355505").each {|m| puts m.author.inspect}
#    "393664355505"
#    "393664355505"
#    "393664355505"
#    "393664355505"
#    "393664355505"
#    "393664355505"

If I attempt a query with a where:
SearchService::Models::Message.search(where: {author: ["393664355505", "7143920115690860", "7714575665265533"]})
#=> #<Searchkick::Relation []>

I really don't understand how this is supposed to work honestly. I'm only trying to have the "author" field used to filter out the results that don't have an author with those ids.
What am I doing wrong?

What does your schema look like? What does your Message model look like?   Is Author a relation to Message? Have you tried passing those values as Integers rather than Strings? I am not all that familiar with Searchkick so these are just suggestions on how to improve the post and other testing options.

just a string, look at m.author.inspect

inspect will always return a String. As stated in the Docs: "Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of obj." e.g. 123.inspect => "123"
